# Applying a border to a CSS transform perspective image

Tags: border, css, css-transforms

So I'm trying to skew a static Google map result so it looks like you're looking down "into it".  Anyway, i've got it working using CSS3 transforms:

```
<html><head>
<style>
.container {
    margin-left: 200px;
    -webkit-perspective: 600;    
       -moz-perspective: 600;
        -ms-perspective: 600;
         -o-perspective: 600;
            perspective:600;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: top;
       -moz-perspective-origin: top;
        -ms-perspective-origin: top;
         -o-perspective-origin: top;
            perspective-origin: top;                
    width: 400px;
}

.test {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(89deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateX(80deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateX(80deg);
         -o-transform: rotateX(80deg);
            transform: rotateX(80deg);
}

img.map {
    border-radius: 200px;
}
</style></head><body>
<div class=container>
<div class=test><img class="map" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=18&sensor=false&scale=1&format=png&maptype=roadmap&size=400x400&markers=icon:http://tron.robotholocaust.com/pin2.png%7Cshadow:false%7C40.714728,-73.998672"></div>
```

Which gives you:

[image: scaled image]

I'd like to put a border around that though.

If I add

```
img.map{
    border: 5px solid;
    border-radius: 200px;    
}
```

I instead get:

[image: bad borders!]

How can I get that border to apply properly?  Do I need to do some other CSS trick? (And yes, this only works in Chrome & Safari regardless of the other extensions I've added sadly).

Comment: have you tried wrapping `img` in `div` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works, if you apply the same radius to the `.test` element, and put the border there (but you may prefer the border on the actual `img` tag; I couldn't solve that.

```
.test {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 200px;
}
```

Comment: d'oh.  I thought I tried that.  I must not have done it right because shit works now.  Thanks dude!

Comment: there is no reason to specify `border-radius` in pixels, if you just want a circle ;) `50%` works same and better. http://jsfiddle.net/QpFy6/